# Strange UICollectionView Selection Behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uicollectionview

I'm using a `UICollectionView` to display a menu, and the items are being selected in a VERY strange way.

Here is my static data that populates them:

```
self.menuItems = @[@{@"text" : @"First", @"image" : @"180-stickynote.png"},
                   @{@"text" : @"Second", @"image" : @"180-stickynote.png"},
                   @{@"text" : @"Third", @"image" : @"180-stickynote.png"},
                   @{@"text" : @"Fourth", @"image" : @"180-stickynote.png"},
                   @{@"text" : @"Fifth", @"image" : @"180-stickynote.png"},
                   @{@"text" : @"Sixth", @"image" : @"180-stickynote.png"}];
```

And the cell provider, where the custom subclass is just attached to the prototype cell and has a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CUMenuCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MenuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *cellInfo = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[cellInfo valueForKey:@"image"]];

    cell.label.text = [cellInfo valueForKey:@"text"];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the did select row method, logging the title, and the row of the item (they're all in section 0):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@: %d", [[self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"text"], indexPath.row);
}
```

Lastly, the screenshot of my menu:

[image]

Here is the log when I select the items from First to Sixth, then back from Sixth to First (First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth, Sixth, Fifth, Fourth, Third, Second, First) (12 total taps, note that the first tap doesn't even register, nor does the second Sixth tap):

```
------------------------------------- FIRST TAP ON FIRST HERE
2013-02-13 19:38:37.343 App[1383:c07] First: 0  // second tap, on Second
2013-02-13 19:38:38.095 App[1383:c07] Second: 1 // third tap, on Third
2013-02-13 19:38:38.678 App[1383:c07] Third: 2  // fourth tap, on Fourth
2013-02-13 19:38:39.375 App[1383:c07] Fourth: 3 // fifth tap, on Fifth
2013-02-13 19:38:40.167 App[1383:c07] Fifth: 4  // so on
2013-02-13 19:38:41.751 App[1383:c07] Sixth: 5
------------------------------------- SECOND TAP ON SIXTH HERE
2013-02-13 19:38:42.654 App[1383:c07] Fifth: 4
2013-02-13 19:38:43.318 App[1383:c07] Fourth: 3
2013-02-13 19:38:44.495 App[1383:c07] Third: 2
2013-02-13 19:38:45.071 App[1383:c07] Second: 1
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That's because you are using `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:` method instead of `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`. An easy mistake to make, especially if you're using code completion when you type it in.

Comment: Wow. I might scream a little, way too late right now. Thank you so much, sincerely!

Comment: @Josh, no problem, it's a mistake I've made more than once.

Comment: Wow. Made this mistake too. Thought there was some dark magik at work. But no. Had myself fooled big time :)

Comment: Since 6 hours I was looking why I select one previous :-)

Comment: StackOverflow... where I feel like time travel has become a reality!. Somehow you came to the future from the past to read some code I just wrote and point out a typo. This site rocks and so do you.

Comment: While not 6 hours - it was close to that. Great answer.

Comment: Spent exactly 1 minute on this - very weird looking - issue thanks to SO and thanks to you. So thank you! Code completion got me there, indeed.

Comment: Hapend to me as well ... :s

Comment: Oh my god, you saved my day! Kiss